# how do I make content transition right to left

Tags: javascript, tabs, css-transitions

[links on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxrBM.jpg)

Hi!
The above picture is the links on the page I want to build (T&C is the active link and has its own content below it), wherein whenever someone clicks on another link, for instance, FAQ, the text should move from right to left smoothly and occupy t&C current position and display its own content.

I was trying this via bootstrap tabs but no luck, is there any different approach to it?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
      <h3>Tabs With Dropdown Menu</h3>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-3</a></li>                        
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you should add your code. see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

*(I can't comment yet, so I put it in an answer)*
Please add the HTML and CSS (and maybe JS) source code to get help.